# EasierCAP works in video, but no audio, even though

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, video

EasierCAP works in video, but no audio, even though `pavucontrol` does seem to be showing variations. I tried VLC, ffmpeg, mplayer... All result in the same: Video but no sound.
The audio level indicator acts strangely: There is continuously a signal present,
and the audio just slightly 'modulates' it... BTW, there *is* audio on the cable: I can hear the audio if I connect a hi-z headphone.

The simple form is using mplayer:
`mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:norm=PAL-NI:width=720:height=576:outfmt=uyvy:device=/dev/video1:input=0:fps=25`

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
...
card 2: C525 [MS210x], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
...
```

so, I tried to add `adevice=hw.2,1` (the ':' replaced by '.' as per `man mplayer`. No complaints but neither audio.

I *am* somewhat confused with the 'C525' in the card title: C525 seems to be model of my webcam...

I found tens of similar reports, but no real solutions - at least none that worked here. Maybe I could record video and sound separately and combine them (as proposed somewhere). But that's not really an elegant solution...